# Extract coefficients from mathematical linear expression in Python

Tags: python, parsing, expression

Given a string containing a linear expression in some variables whose name might be not known, I would like to return a dictionary having the variable names as keys and the respective coefficients as values.

**Example**

Input:

```
s = "- x0 + 2 * x1 + 4 * x2 - 3 * y + z + 8"
```

Output:

```
{'x0': -1, 'x1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y': -3, 'z': 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like `([+-])?\s*(?:(\d+)\s*\*\s*)?([a-z]\w*)`. Here, the first part (the coefficient, including `*`) is optional, but only the sign and the actual number will the memorized, as well as the variable. Then, You can convert those to a dict.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "- x0 + 2 * x1 + 4 * x2 - 3 * y + z + 8"
>>> p = r"([+-])?\s*(?:(\d+)\s*\*\s*)?([a-z]\w*)"
>>> re.findall(p, s)
[('-', '', 'x0'),
 ('+', '2', 'x1'),
 ('+', '4', 'x2'),
 ('-', '3', 'y'),
 ('+', '', 'z')]
>>> {v: int(s+(c or '1')) for (s, c, v) in _ }
{'x0': -1, 'x1': 2, 'x2': 4, 'y': -3, 'z': 1}
```

Breakdown of the regex:

- `([+-])?\s*`: Optional sign, followed by spaces
- `(?:(\d+)\s*\*\s*)?` Optional coefficient, followed by `*` and spaces; only the actual digits is captured
- `([a-z]\w*)`: Name of the variable

Comment: Thanks! Please check the edited question: it does not work properly for the new example with `- x0`